# Is there any way to remove current profile picture from Skype?

Tags: skype-for-web

I want to remove the picture not to replace it with another.

---

This was asked two years ago, I had forgotten about this one. The new version of Skype has an option to remove/hide profile picture:

[image: Settings options]

Still haven't found relevant information on removing it using the web version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a desktop application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to replace the image with a generic picture, like the Skype logo or a blank user avatar picture.

As far as I know, you cannot remove a profile image once one is added as it is stored on Skype's servers. The other option would be to create a new account.

Comment: yeah I also could find only the option to replace profile picture.